# How to keep using values from a list until the diagonal of a matrix is full using itertools

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, list-comprehension, python-itertools, diagonal

So I am trying to use a smaller list to populate the diagonal of a larger matrix. I thought using the cycle function in itertools would make this an easy task but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I tried

```
a = np.zeros((10,10))
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(a.shape[0])):
     a[i, i] = list(itertools.cycle(b))
```

but this makes it endlessly iterate. I am hoping that it will stop once the diagonal has been filled. Other options that are more pythonic are greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are you trying? to set the diags to 1 then 2, then 3 etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean to use `itertools.cycle`, not `repeat`. The latter repeats the element (the list), good luck setting that into a value, specially if you force iteration (since it runs forever)

I'd create a reference on a `cycle` object outside the loop and assign a value to the diagonal iterating over it manually (the only proper way with `cycle`). Also note that your loop `range` was wrong. `a.shape[0]` is a dimension, no need for `len`

```
import numpy as np,itertools
a = np.zeros((10,10))
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
iterator = itertools.cycle(b)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     a[i, i] = next(iterator)
```

result:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.]])
```

As they loop forever, `cycle` and `repeat` should not be used in a context of forced iteration (`repeat` has an optional parameter to limit the repeats, though).

Comment: I mean't to put cycle in my original post, oops. But my issue was that I wasn't using it as an iterator outside the loop and not using next! Thank you.

Comment: those are evil "infinite loop" twins when misused :)